# Android robolectric tests manifest merge issue (android beacon library)

Tags: android, robolectric, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I have the simple Test Case

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class BaseTest  {

   @Test
   public void startEverTestSugarAppAsFirst() {
       BeaconManager.setsManifestCheckingDisabled(true);
   }

}
```

Unfortunately the runner hits manifestmerger issue

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager$ServiceNotDeclaredException: The
>   BeaconService is not properly declared in AndroidManifest.xml.  If
>   using Eclipse, please verify that your project.properties has
>   manifestmerger.enabled=true
>
> at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:256)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:193)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:56)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:159)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by:
>   org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager$ServiceNotDeclaredException: The
>   BeaconService is not properly declared in AndroidManifest.xml.  If
>   using Eclipse, please verify that your project.properties has
>   manifestmerger.enabled=true   at
>   org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.verifyServiceDeclaration(BeaconManager.java:786)
>     at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.(BeaconManager.java:252)
>     at
>   org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(BeaconManager.java:244)
>     at com.lucyapp.client.Client.onCreate(Client.java:67)   at
>   org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:164)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:421)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:252)
>     ... 18 more

I wonder if there is any simple work around. I've been going through android beacon library test folder and

```
BeaconManager.setsManifestCheckingDisabled(true);
```

doesn't help

Comment: Where do you put that line?  That's exactly what I do to get around the issue.

Comment: The first line in test (The same as in the library test package). It's on the top of my question.

Comment: Do you think it might be a bug that should be submitted within a new issue on github ?

Comment: Let's troubleshoot here a bit more before creating an issue in GitHub.  Either way, I'm the guy who will be helping you.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the `BeaconManager` is being constructed *before* the call to `BeaconManager.setsManifestCheckingDisabled(true);`  The trick is to figure out where to put that line so it does get executed first.

Looking at the stack trace, I see that the `BeaconManager` gets constructed from `com.lucyapp.client.Client.onCreate` on line 67:

```
...
org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(BeaconManager.java:244) at 
com.lucyapp.client.Client.onCreate(Client.java:67)
...
```

Knowing that, perhaps you can figure out where you can put the `BeaconManager.setsManifestCheckingDisabled(true);` line such that it gets called before `com.lucyapp.client.Client.onCreate(Client.java:67)`

Comment: I've suspected the same. Client is the android application. Seemed like I need to refactor my code a bit to make it work. If I disable the manifest check in code (just to test) I get another error in RangeNotifier. Will come back here if I have something new.